# How to determine The typeface(font-style) ?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, typeface

I want to Get the font-style of different fonts i-e **Algerian,Arial**  . . . . . . .

Every Font has its own font-style i-e **Arial**(Narrow,Narrow Italic,italic,Regular,Norrow bold,bold)  AND **Algerian**(regular,Extra condensed,Extra condensed italic,Extra condensed bold).
i got all the font names from google. (https://www.googleapis.comwebfontsv1webfonts?key=AIza#################).

Kindly tell me that how i can get the style of each font.

Comment: that link doesn't work...you want font names and styles for...google web fonts?

Comment: thanks for Comment Albert But I already found the Solution.  :) :)